# jQuery 'remove anchor before scroll' function not working in firefox but working perfect in chrome,safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function that removes the anchor '#categorie' in the url, to prevent the website from scrolling to the section with that id. 
This is works perfect in Chrome and Safari. However in firefox it doesn't, well it does but only partly.

This is the html structure of the item I click on:

```
<div class="person kernteam abigael-verspoor">
    <div class="person-img">
       <a href="http://www.ludenstraining.nl/person1/#kernteam">
       <img src="person1"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="person-info">
       <h3><a href="http://www.ludenstraining.nl/person1/#kernteam">Abigael Verspoor</a></h3>
       <p>programmamanager / trainer / coach</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery code that prevents the anchor scroll from happening:

```
  // right away before the browser can start scrolling!
  var hash = window.location.hash,
      target = hash.replace('#', '');

  // delete hash so the page won't scroll to it
  window.location.hash = "";
```

I tried fixing it by setting a time out function where the window scroll back to 0 top but that doesn't work either, at least not consistent.

To actually see it live go to this link:http://www.ludenstraining.nl/over-ons/

In chrome and safari it will work perfect. In firefox it seems to work at first but only for the first tab 'kernteam'. In the second and third tab you will see it scrolling down to the categorie tab the person is connected to.

I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Would you like to share with us why it has the hash if you do not want it?

Comment: Because I put the hash of the url in a value that I use on the page. Otherwise I would've just removed it of course.

Comment: so use data-attribute: `<a href="...." data-team="kernteam" ....` or change to #prefix_kernteam so it does not go to id="kernteam"

Comment: Thanks I got it, you put me in the right direction. Putting a prefix breaks the link but I found a solution by replacing the anchor links '#' with '?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify it in a way that it works in firefox too.
The biggest part of it was replacing the anchor '#' on links with '?'.

Doing this will prevent the page scrolling to element with that ID in Firefox.
To extract the value form the link I used this:

```
var url = window.location.href;//get url
var urlsplit = url.split('?');//split url from '?'
var tab = urlsplit[1]; get the url part after '?'
```

It worked a lot better for me because you won't have the struggle of needing to remove an anchor jump before a page load. Plus you don't have the trouble of not being able to properly reload because of removing the anchor.

Thanks to mplunjan for helping getting me to this solution.

Comment: location.search.substring(1) makes more sense